# SQL - Return only first row that matches

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The table `dbo.AllApps` logs all executable that has been run it has a column named `ApplicationHash` which stores the exe hash value.  
So if the exe has been run 10 times, there will be 10 entries in table with the same information but different timestamp.  
I would like to produce a report that will only return 1 row from the 10 (with all columns time,name,desc ...) and one additional column that will provide the count of the number of times the exe has been executed.  
Any suggestions?

```
`/* !!!!!DEFINE START AND END DATE FOR REPORT HERE!!!!!*/
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = 2017-01-01
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = 2017-01-02`

`/* Checks if the temp table #PCount exist and deletes the table if it does */
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#PCount') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE #PCount
END`

`/* Performs a COUNT on the ApplicationHash entries */
SELECT ApplicationHash, COUNT(ApplicationHash) AS ProcessCount
INTO #PCount
FROM dbo.AllApps 
WHERE
TokenType = 'Elevated' 
AND ApplicationType != 'COM Class'
AND ApplicationType != 'ActiveX Control'
AND ProcessStartTime >= @StartDate
AND ProcessStartTime < @EndDAte
GROUP BY ApplicationHash`

`/* Pulls up the actual report and inserts the count value for the ApplicationHash */
SELECT #PCount.ProcessCount, 
dbo.AllApps.ApplicationHash, 
dbo.AllApps.ProcessStartTime,
dbo.AllApps.ApplicationType,
dbo.AllApps.Description, 
dbo.AllApps.Publisher, 
dbo.AllApps.ProductName, 
dbo.AllApps.ProductVersion, 
dbo.AllApps.EventDescription, 
dbo.AllApps.CommandLine, 
dbo.AllApps.FileName
FROM #PCount, dbo.AllApps 
WHERE dbo.AllApps.ApplicationHash = #PCount.ApplicationHash
AND TokenType = 'Elevated'
AND ApplicationType != 'COM Class'
AND ApplicationType != 'ActiveX Control'
AND ProcessStartTime >= @StartDate
AND ProcessStartTime < @EndDate
ORDER BY ProcessStartTime DESC`
```

Comment: in sql server you just prefix the field list with `TOP 1` to get the first row.

Comment: And out of the 10 rows, which one would you like to read time, name, desc etc. from?

Comment: @Hogan - This is only true if you want just the first row, not the first row for all `ApplicationHash` values.

Comment: @LaughingVergil true... then row_number() is best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [**`top with ties`**](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/use-top-filter-with-ties-option) with [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to get the row with the most recent `ProccessStartTime` and [**`count(*) over()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) for the `ProcessCount`.

Note: the temporary table is not needed for this solution. If the `where` criteria were not the same for both queries, then it would be a different story.

Update: Without knowing more about the data types and the presence of a unique id for rows on this table, I have added a `case` expression to include the `ProcessStartTime` to the partition when `ApplicationHash` = `<None>`, else a constant (`@StartDate`).

```
declare @StartDate datetime = '20170101';
declare @EndDate datetime   = '20170102';

select top 1 with ties
    ProcessCount = count(*) over (
      partition by ApplicationHash 
        , case 
          when ApplicationHash = '<None>' 
            then ProcessStartTime
          else @StartDate
          end 
      order by ProcessStartTime desc
      )
  , ApplicationHash
  , ProcessStartTime
  , ApplicationType
  , Description
  , Publisher
  , ProductName
  , ProductVersion
  , EventDescription
  , CommandLine
  , FileName
from dbo.AllApps aa
where TokenType = 'Elevated' 
  and ApplicationType != 'com Class'
  and ApplicationType != 'ActiveX Control'
  and ProcessStartTime >= @StartDate
  and ProcessStartTime < @EndDate
order by row_number() over (
  partition by ApplicationHash
    , case 
      when ApplicationHash = '<None>' 
        then ProcessStartTime
      else @StartDate
      end
  order by ProcessStartTime desc
  )
```

Comment: This works thanks, could this be modified further for the following? The column "ApplicationHash" has some entries with the value "<None>", these are instances where the hash was not calculated would it be possible to list all rows with ApplicationHash = "<None>" combined with the results from the code you provided?

Comment: This works thanks, could this be modified further for the following? The column "ApplicationHash" has some entries with the value "<None>", these are instances where the hash was not calculated. Would it be possible to list all rows with ApplicationHash = "<None>" combined with the results from the code you provided?

Comment: @AlexJP Is there a unique id on this table? What is the datatype and size of `ApplicationHash`?

Comment: ApplicationHash is nVarChar(40) no NULL. I'm querying from a views table. Doesn't look like there is a unique id, there is a column called "UniqueID" but i found a few duplicates in this field. However the duplicates seem to have exact same data for all fields.

Comment: Would it be possible to add the following? In the table dbo.AllApps there is a column called UserName. Like how ProcessCount was calculated by getting the number of times a unique value in ApplicationHash repeats, can we count the total number of unique UserName for a unique ApplicationHash value? Example ApplicationHash ABCDE12345 repeats 10 times (so this is the process count) but in these 10 times, 5 of this records User123 and another 5 User456, thus making the UserName Count to 2.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to use a cte and row_number:

```
;with cte as
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ApplicationHash ORDER BY ProcessStartTime) as rn,
#PCount.ProcessCount, 
dbo.AllApps.ApplicationHash, 
dbo.AllApps.ProcessStartTime,
dbo.AllApps.ApplicationType,
dbo.AllApps.Description, 
dbo.AllApps.Publisher, 
dbo.AllApps.ProductName, 
dbo.AllApps.ProductVersion, 
dbo.AllApps.EventDescription, 
dbo.AllApps.CommandLine, 
dbo.AllApps.FileName
FROM #PCount
INNER JOIN dbo.AllApps ON dbo.AllApps.ApplicationHash = #PCount.ApplicationHash
WHERE TokenType = 'Elevated'
AND ApplicationType != 'COM Class'
AND ApplicationType != 'ActiveX Control'
AND ProcessStartTime >= @StartDate
AND ProcessStartTime < @EndDate
)

SELECT ProcessCount, 
       ApplicationHash, 
       ProcessStartTime,
       ApplicationType,
       Description, 
       Publisher, 
       ProductName, 
       ProductVersion, 
       EventDescription, 
       CommandLine, 
       FileName
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
```

Please note I've changed your implicit join to an explicit join.
Read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) to find out why.

Comment: This doesn't work, i get the following error: Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 26
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: Partially works, it returns 1 row instead of 44 rows which it should.

Comment: Should add `partition by` to the row number. Will edit on a few minutes.

Comment: Edited my answer.